# How to stop a rigid body sliding

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have a car going down a slope and would like it to turn. It rolls nicely using rigid body constraints, but when I turn the front tires it just continues in the same direction like it is on ice. There is a little bouncing like the tires are trying to grab, but mostly has no effect.

To attempt to figure it out I upped the friction of the front wheel and ground plane to 10 million, steps per second to 600 and solver iterations to 60.

Any ideas of what I am missing? Thanks!

[image]
  The relationship lines show where the car started. The back wheels have a motor constraints which is pushing it quite nicely, just won't turn no matter what I do.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?